# .NET: Decimal to rounded string

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

If I have a `decimal`, how do I get a string version of it with two decimal places? This isn't working:

```
Math.Round(myDecimal, 2).ToString("{0.00}");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the curly brackets, they are for embedding a formatted value in a longer string using `string.Format`. Use this:

```
myDecimal.ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: Note that the format string `"{0.00}"` wouldn't work for `string.Format` either; you'd have to use `"{0:0.00}"` there.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe i'm wrong, but i've tried `myDecimal.ToString();` and it worked.

Comment: +1 : Unlike `float` and `double`, the `decimal` data type will retain the number of digits of precision, so `Math.Round(myDecimal, 2).ToString();` should work just fine. No format string required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myDecimal` is a `System.Decimal`, then `Math.Round(myDecimal, 2).ToString();` will display two decimal digits of precision, just as you want, without any format string (unless the absolute value of your number is greater than 10^27-1). This is because the `decimal` datatype retains full precision of the number. That is to say that `1m`, `1.0m`, and `1.00m` are all stored differently and will display differently.

Note that this is not true of `float` or `double`. `1f`, `1.0f`, and `1.00f` are stored and display identically, as do `1d`, `1.0d`, and `1.00d`.

Since the format string must be parsed at runtime, I would probably omit it for code like this in most cases.